# How to extract keys from the following definitions (not the standard association)?

Tags: syntax, associations

Consider some example definitions:

```
abba["1"] = 1;
abba["2"] = 2;
```

For some reason, I do not want to introduce the other form of representation such as associations.

Is it possible at all to extract keys for which `abba` takes the predefined values (i.e., "1","2")?

Comment: `lookUp =  ReplaceAll[
   Merge[Identity] @ Map[Reverse] @
     ReleaseHold[ DownValues[#] /. {RuleDelayed -> Rule, #[x_] :> x}]] &;` Use as  `lookUp[abba]@{1, 2}`, `lookUp[abba]@2` etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Keys[DownValues[abba]][[All, 1, 1]]
(* {"1", "2"} *)
```